# python dataframe group rows based on row num

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 40 rows,
and I want to iterate over it so I will have 4 iteration with 10 rows each, serially.

So group#0 will be rows 0-9 , group#1 will be rows 10-19 and so on.

How can I do it?

Comment: You should write your question in [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solutions from this stackoverflow question : [How to iterate over consecutive chunks of Pandas dataframe efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699439/how-to-iterate-over-consecutive-chunks-of-pandas-dataframe-efficiently)

I advise you to check the link.

Solution from DSM :

```py
for k,g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10):
    print(k,g)
```

Solution from Ryan :

```py
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))

for i in chunker(df,5):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = {
    'State':['Arizona','Georgia','Newyork','Indiana','Florida'],
   'Score1':[4,47,55,74,31]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['State','Score1'])
print(df1)
```

We need to add value (here 430) to the index to generate row number and the result is stored in a new column as shown below.

```
df1['New_ID'] = df1.index + 430
print(df1)
```

Comment: Could you explain in your answer how to iterate over the dataframe now with your proposed solution, as was asked in the Question?