# Get the pandas dataframe in chunks without repetition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, generator

I've looked into the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699439/how-to-iterate-over-consecutive-chunks-of-pandas-dataframe-efficiently) along with several others and I may be dead tired that I am making this mistake and can't figure out exactly where. I basically want to split a pandas dataframe into chunks and send it piece by piece via JSON to an API endpoint. I don't want the same row to be sent multiple times. My question is in **Step 4** in the process below.

**Reproducible example**

**Step 1: Dataframe Creation**

```
# Dataframe Creation

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filenames = ["file_"+str(x) for x in np.arange(1, 11)]
languages = ['en', 'en', 'fr', 'en', 'en', 'en', 'es', 'en', 'fr', 'en']

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'file': filenames, 'lang': languages})
```

**Step 1 Output**

```
file    lang
0   file_1  en
1   file_2  en
2   file_3  fr
3   file_4  en
4   file_5  en
5   file_6  en
6   file_7  es
7   file_8  en
8   file_9  fr
9   file_10 en
```

**Step 2 - two functions**

```
def get_chunk_df(large_df, splits):
    """splits df into chunks"""
    for chunk_df in np.array_split(large_df, splits):
        yield chunk_df


def get_json_chunks(df, splits):
    """converts each chunk to a dict which is basically going to be a JSON load"""
    documents = {"documents": []}
    df_chunks = get_chunk_df(df, splits)
    for chunk_df in df_chunks:
        for idx, row in chunk_df.iterrows():
            documents["documents"].append({
                "id": str(idx + 1),
                "text": row["lang"]
            })
        yield documents
```

**Step 3 - Testing the output of get_chunk_df function - which is OK**

```
chunk_gen = get_chunk_df(test_df, 3)
counter = 0
for chk in chunk_gen:
    counter = counter + 1
    print(f"***********PRINTING {counter} CHUNK...")
    print(chk)
```

**Step 3 Output**

```
***********PRINTING 1 CHUNK...
     file lang
0  file_1   en
1  file_2   en
2  file_3   fr
3  file_4   en
***********PRINTING 2 CHUNK...
     file lang
4  file_5   en
5  file_6   en
6  file_7   es
***********PRINTING 3 CHUNK...
      file lang
7   file_8   en
8   file_9   fr
9  file_10   en
```

**Step 4 - My problem is here**

```
json_chunks = get_json_chunks(test_df, 3)

for json_chk in json_chunks:
    print(f"First row: {json_chk['documents'][0]}")
    print(f"Last row: {json_chk['documents'][-1]}")
```

**Step 4 Output**

```
First row: {'id': '1', 'text': 'en'}
Last row: {'id': '4', 'text': 'en'}
First row: {'id': '1', 'text': 'en'}
Last row: {'id': '7', 'text': 'es'}
First row: {'id': '1', 'text': 'en'}
Last row: {'id': '10', 'text': 'en'}
```

But I want the **Expected Output** to be:

```
First row: {'id': '1', 'text': 'en'}
Last row: {'id': '4', 'text': 'en'}
First row: {'id': '5', 'text': 'en'}
Last row: {'id': '7', 'text': 'es'}
First row: {'id': '8', 'text': 'en'}
Last row: {'id': '10', 'text': 'en'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you use `append()` in `get_json_chunks` so maybe this is why you always have old rows in dataframe.

Comment: @furas I literally just noticed that and was about to answer my own question :) . Feel free to answer it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `documents = {"documents": []}` before `for`-loop and later you `append` to the same `documents` but you have to create new `documents` inside `for`-loop

```
def get_json_chunks(df, splits):
    """converts each chunk to a dict which is basically going to be a JSON load"""
    
    #documents = {"documents": []}  # <-- wrong place
    df_chunks = get_chunk_df(df, splits)
    
    for chunk_df in df_chunks:

        documents = {"documents": []}  # <-- good place

        for idx, row in chunk_df.iterrows():
            documents["documents"].append({
                "id": str(idx + 1),
                "text": row["lang"]
            })

        yield documents
```